# Combine rights from 2 SQL-users

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic

Is it anyhow possible to merge 2 SQL logins, so that I can access 2 databases with different logins at the same server?

I'm using ASP Classic (ADODB) and SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use two different sets of credentials you'll need to use two connection objects (or constantly close and reopen one).

Eg:

```
<%
    dim dbA, dbB

    Set dbA = server.createobject("adodb.connection")
    Set dbB = server.createobject("adodb.connection")
    Set rs  = server.createobject("adodb.recordset")

    dbA.open "ConnectionStringForYourFirstDatabase"
    dbB.open "ConnectionStringForYourSecondDatabase"

    '#### Execute something to database 1 using connection string 1
    set rs = dbA.execute("")

    '#### Execute something to database 2 using connection string 2
    set rs = dbB.execute("")

    '#### Tidy Up
    set dbA = nothing
    set dbB = nothing
%>
```

Comment: That all depends on your definition of "merge" but yes, SQL server only accepts one set of credentials per connection, you'd either need to give 1 set of credentials access to both databases and include the database name in your queries, or use two connections as per my answer.

Comment: I knew about the multiple connections, I just hoped for a better solution :) But thanks for the answer :)